# Need Multiple JPanel's to respond its own mouse click events

Tags: java, mouseevent, jpanel

I have multiple JPanels on my application, however I cannot figure out how to detect which exactly which one was clicked.

In my MouseListener, I have the argument      e    but my method isn't working

Early in my code I declare multiple JPanels and a listener object.

```
PuzzleListener plist = new PuzzleListener();
JPanel puzzle_board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,5,5));
...
Square square1 = new Square("1");
Square square2 = new Square("2");
...
puzzle_board.add(square1);
puzzle_board.add(square2);
...
square1.addMouseListener(plist);
square1.addMouseListener(plist);
```

class PuzzleListener implements MouseListener
    {

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
 {
       JPanel pnlClick = (JPanel)(e.getSource());
       //System.out.println(pnlClick);
  //System.out.println(e.getSource());
  //System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClass());
  //System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClass().getName());


            //problem is here

  if(pnlClick == square1)
  {
   System.out.println("Panel 1 has been clicked");
  }    
            if(pnlClick == square2)
  {
   System.out.println("Panel 2 has been clicked");
  }       
 }
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
 {
 }
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
 { 
  //System.out.println("Panel 1 has been clicked");
 }
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
 {
 }
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }
 /*
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  JPanel pnlClick = (JPanel)(e.getSource());
 }*/

}//end calcListener

Comment: I totally forgot to accept my previous answers =)   Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would appear to be that you have a class variable and a local variable for each of your square panels.

```
Square square1 = new Square("1");
```

should be:

```
square1 = new Square("1");
```

now you will only have a class variable which the PuzzleListener can reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to use a single MouseListener? You could create a new instance of your PuzzleListener and add it to each JPanel. That way there is no confusion as to which listener on which panel is getting fired.

Comment: This is a shortened version of my code, I actually have 16 JPanels on 1 JFrame. Sounds weird but those are the project requirements.